# Extract the rest string of the matched one in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, substring

I have searched for this on the Internet, but cannot really find the proper approach to it.
I want to extract the rest of the string out of the found one. Example field/column: 1_Google_en, 2_Google_de, 3_Google_fr, 4_Google_tw, Apple_en, Apple_de, Apple_cn
If I do

```
select * from db.table where field_1 like "%Google%"
```

I get those fields.
But how can I modify the fields so that it gives me for those matched with "%Google%" all of the rest split in 2 fields? i.e. field_1: 1,2,3,4. field_2: en, de, fr, tw.
Is that doable with a some sort of a function take everything but not the matched string? Would be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understood question but interpreting as given a  search string, you want to get the text before the search string and the text after the search string.

Using 1_Google_en as example:

SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, 'Google', 1) should give you '1_'

SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, 'Google', -1) should give you '_en'

Take a look at http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php